# How do I use a coroutine to do some calculation in parallel to the main process in C++?

Tags: c++, performance, rendering, coroutine

I am currently working on a project using a Microsoft's Azure Kinect SDK. I'm taking video feed from a depth camera as input and rendering the depth video. My application uses body tracking, and i am trying to highlight objects that the tracked body touches in a particular color. I do this by constantly calculating the distance between the body and all the pixels, and considering them as having been touched once that distance is below a certain threshold. It is working, but the rendering is quite slow. I believe it is being slowed down because of the distance calculation. I'd like to do this distance calculation with a coroutine, so that the rendering can continue while the calculation is being done. I have done similar things in Unity with C#, but I've looked through C++'s coroutine documentation and can't quite figure it out.

How do I take a function that I've written, and use a coroutine to make it run in parallel to the main function?

Comment: I think you have coroutines confused with threads.

Comment: Yes, I suppose the way I described it is more like a thread. They don't have to be parallel, I just want the program to pause the distance calculation if its not done in time to make a certain frame rate, and then pick up execution again on the next frame.